# Javascript College CA Bug

Tags: javascript

I have an error in my code.

The objective is that if the user buys enough jersey's that is over €250 I have to discount everything that comes next after it at 15%.

The first part of my code works (If cost <= 250) the anything above gives me a (NaN).

My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <title>
        Q1 - Jerseys
    </title>

    <style  type="text/css">
    </style>

    <script>
        "use strict";

        function processOrder()
        {
            //Calculations for Order
            var type = document.getElementById("getType").value;
            var number = parseInt(document.getElementById("getNumber").value);
            var cost;
            var PER_FIVE = parseFloat(0.15);
            var overPrice = cost - 250;

            //Logo Variables
            var logo = document.getElementById("getLogo").value || "N";
            var logoCost = 1.50;

            //Empty Variables for Returned Values
            var outputText;

            //Polo Shirt Case
            if (type === "Polo" && logo === "Y")
            {
                cost = (number * (22.50 + logoCost));

            } else if (type === "Polo" && logo === "N") {

                cost = parseFloat(number * 22.50);

            }//End Polo

            //Short Sleeve Case
            if (type === "Short" && logo === "Y") {

                cost = (number * (22.50 + logoCost));

            } else if (type === "Short" && logo === "N") {

                cost = number * 25.50;

            }//End Short

            //Long Sleeve Case
            if (type === "Long" && logo === "Y") {

                cost = (number * (22.50 + logoCost));

            } else if (type === "Long" && logo === "N") {

                cost = number * 28.50;

            }//End Long

            //Output To "results" Text Area
            if (cost <= 250) {

                outputText = "The cost of your jerseys is €" + cost;
                document.getElementById("results").value = outputText;

            } else if (cost > 250) {

                outputText = "The cost of your jerseys is €" + (250 +       (overPrice - (overPrice * PER_FIVE)));
                document.getElementById("results").value = outputText;

            }//End If

        }//End Function


    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    Please Enter details of your jersey order:
    <br> <br>
    Type of jersey (Polo, Short,Long):
    <input id="getType" />
    <br> <br>

    Number of Jerseys:
    <input id="getNumber" />
    <br> <br>

    Add A Logo:
    <input id="getLogo" maxlength="1"/> Type: "Y" or "N".
    <br> <br>

    <button onclick="processOrder()" >Click to see results below</button>
    <br> <br>

    Results:
    <br>
    <textarea id="results" rows="4" cols="50" readonly >
    </textarea>

  </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Try keeping your math, and your string concatenation separate.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning `overPrice` before `cost` has been determined:

```
var overPrice = cost - 250;
```

At this point `cost` is `undefined`, and `undefined - 250` is what's giving you `NaN`.

Variables aren't dynamic in this way - updating `cost` won't automatically update `overPrice` - you need to set it once you know the value of `cost`.  Within your `else if` block would be appropriate since it is not needed elsewhere:

```
//Output To "results" Text Area
if (cost <= 250) {
     outputText = "The cost of your jerseys is €" + cost;
     document.getElementById("results").value = outputText;
} else if (cost > 250) {
    var overPrice = cost - 250;
    outputText = "The cost of your jerseys is €" + (250 +       (overPrice - (overPrice * PER_FIVE)));
    document.getElementById("results").value = outputText;
}//End If
```

---

On a separate note, you're using `parseInt` without specifying the radix parameter.  [It's recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix) to always specify it to avoid potential issues:

```
var number = parseInt(document.getElementById("getNumber").value, 10);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast answer and the help!